# Display subcategory of every category from database on hover over the category name in php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap

Having gone through some solutions provided here, I could not still get it right. Only the subcategory of the last category is being fetched and display from the database when I hover on the category name.

```
    <div class="mega-menu-category">
      <ul class="nav">
        <!-- Other side-menu navs -->
        <?php $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,categoryName FROM category");
         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
          {
            ?>
          <li><a href="category.php?cid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['categoryName'];?></a>
            <?php
            $getid = $row['id'];
            }?>
          <div class="wrap-popup column1">
            <div class="popup">
              <?php $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, subcategory FROM subcategory WHERE categoryid= '$getid'");
               while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                   {
                   ?>
              <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="sub-category.php?scid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row['subcategory']);?></a></li>
              </ul>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>

          </div>
        </li>

        <!-- used one  -->

      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were consuming all the resultset of the outer query and not using it in the inner loop.

Also using the same variable for both queries would have been you next issue, as when you run the inner query, it would destroy the resultset for the outer look

```
<div class="mega-menu-category">
    <ul class="nav">
        <!-- Other side-menu navs -->
<?php 
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,categoryName FROM category");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
?>
        <li><a href="category.php?cid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                <?php echo $row['categoryName'];?>
            </a>
<?php
//}  this causes the first loop to run to its end hence only one category processed
?>
            <div class="wrap-popup column1">
                <div class="popup">
<?php 
    // use different variable otherwise you will destroy the first resultset
    $sql1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id, subcategory 
                                FROM subcategory 
                                WHERE categoryid= '$row[id]'");
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
?>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="sub-category.php?scid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                        <?php echo htmlentities($row1['subcategory']);?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
<?php 
    }  // end inner while
} // end outer while
?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <!-- used one  -->
</ul>
</div>
```

> I do have to mention that you are open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
> Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
> You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Thanks so much @Riggs Folly, this actually do the magic. I also appreciate the resources.